# How to setup a message webhook on Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I want to setup a webhook, which triggers when a user sends the message into Page chat. I need to "pages_messaging" permission for my app. But, Facebook requires a Privacy Policy. But I don't want to distribute my app, I want to test the API for education only. Is it necessary me to have a Privacy Policy?

Comment: No and Facebook does not require it

Comment: I'm sorry, they do not request "Terms of Use" but a "Privacy Policy"

Comment: When do they require that?

Comment: on the page https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<id>/messenger/ . I have a russian translated text: "Укажите поле «URL-адрес политики конфиденциальности» для своего приложения. Чтобы сделать это, перейдите по следующей ссылке: Настройки." Screenshot here: http://pastenow.ru/1QR7Y

Comment: Why are you submitting that permission for review?

Comment: I want send and receive messages from Page automatically (with a bot)

Comment: And? You can ask anyone that have a role on the app for any permission. They don't need to be approved